# Firefox perfomance lagging for large integers

Tags: javascript, firefox

### Backstory

I was playing around with finding large powers of 2.  My method was splitting the large numbers into an array of smaller values and the multiplying each of them to get the next value.  The size I chose for the smaller chunks was a maximum size of `1e15`.  Then I decided to see how performance changed if I used the new array buffers and had to reduce the maximum size down to `1e9`.  Something weird happened I got a performance boost not from using the array buffers, but from using a smaller integer.  This doesn't make sense since the larger the number the fewer times the function has to cycle through the array.

### Code

```
var i=3
function run(){
  loop(50000,Math.pow(10,i),i++);
  if(i<16)setTimeout(run,100)
}
run();

function loop(pin,lim,id){
  var pow=110503;
  pow=pin||pow;
  var l=pow-1,val=[2];
  var t1,t2;
  //console.time(id);
  t1=new Date();
  while(l--){
    val=multiply(val,lim);
  }
  //console.timeEnd(id);
  t2=new Date();
  console.log(id,' ',t2-t1);
}

function multiply(a,lim){
  var l=a.length,val=0,carry=0;
  while(l--){
    val=a[l]*2+carry;
    carry=0;
    if(val>lim-1){
      var b=val%lim;
      carry=(val-b)/lim;
      val=b;
    }
    a[l]=val;
  }
  if(carry>0){a.unshift(carry)}
  return a;
}
```

### Results

IE10

```
 3 5539 
 4 4213 
 5 3329 
 6 2720 
 7 2341 
 8 2153 
 9 1948 
 10 1699 
 11 1508 
 12 1401 
 13 1309 
 14 1208 
 15 1133
```

Chrome

```
3 5962
4 4385
5 3851
6 3242
7 2533
8 2207
9 1940
10 1794
11 1542
12 1604
13 1560
14 1414
15 1331
```

Firefox

```
3 3651 
4 2732 
5 2279 
6 1853 
7 1615 
8 1408 
9 1256 
10 2375 
11 2034 
12 1874 
13 1723 
14 1600 
15 1504
```

### Question

As you can see Firefox outperforms both IE10 and Chrome up til numbers that are 9 digits long and then it takes a sudden jump in time.  So, why does it do this?  I guess it may have something to do with switching between numbers that can by stored in 32 bytes. I suppose 32 byte numbers are more efficient to work with; so for smaller numbers they use them and then switch to a larger integer type if they need to.  But if that is true why does it never catch up to Chrome's and IE's performance and would switching cause that much of a performance penalty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both SpiderMonkey (Firefox) and V8 (Chrome) use 32-bit integers when they can, switching to doubles (not larger integers) when the numbers no longer fit into a 32-bit int.  But note that "can" is determined heuristically, because there are costs to mixing doubles and ints due to having to convert back and forth, so it's possible that V8 is not deciding to specialize to ints here.

Edit: deleted the part about needing the source, since it's all right there in the original post!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I somehow totally missed that.  :(  So when I run that code locally I see the jump when switching to doubles in Firefox, but it continues to be faster than Chrome even after that.  Just to check, what Firefox version were you testing?

Comment: Interesting. I just tried Firefox 19 and Chrome 27 dev on Mac, and for example I get "15 392" in Firefox but "15 448" in Chrome....

Comment: Were you finding the 50000 power because I'm now wishing my laptop could get those times.  Though what may be happening is your processing everything so quickly it doesn't make a difference (or in other words the FF only gets slower for longer running jobs).  But I'm still wondering what FF compared to the other browsers is doing get those times.  Also, thanks for your answer I didn't realize that they went from 32-bit ints to doubles.  I thought they might change to 64-bit ints.

Comment: I'm running the exact code above, so yes, 50000 power...  I wonder whether it's a matter of 32-bit vs 64-bit for some odd reason or something.  In any case, JS numbers are all doubles by definition, so you can't switch to 64-bit ints in general, unless you can prove that all your numbers are staying under 2^53... and maintaining three separate arithmetic paths is a bit of a pain, so no one seems to do it.